# Extracting data from a complicated hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following hash:

```
def menu
  {
    diet: @diet,
    proteins: ["Tofurkey", "Hummus"],
    veggies: [:ginger_carrots, :potatoes, :yams],
    desserts: {
      pies: [:pumpkin_pie],
      other: ["Chocolate Moose"],
      molds: [:cranberry, :mango, :cherry]
    }
  }
end
```

I want to extract the desserts from the hash, and then form a string that says

"Tonight we have 5 delicious desserts: Pumpkin Pie, Chocolate Moose, and 3 molds: Cranberry and Mango and Cherry."

I have the following code:

```
def whats_for_dessert
  "Tonight we have 5 delicious desserts:" +
    menu[:desserts][:pies].flatten.to_s +
    menu[:desserts][:other].to_s
end
```

This code outputs

```
"Tonight we have 5 delicious desserts:[:pumpkin_pie][\"Chocolate Moose\"]"
```

Is there a better way to collect the data so I don't end up with a bunch of awkward characters?

Comment: Don't use an array for the pies? E.g., join with a comma, convert from symbol to string and make it human readable? Don't use symbols to represent human-readable data?

Comment: As suggested think over data structure for the required goal properly. I'd suggest to wrap kinds of meal in a class with all the formatted output methods implemented. Clean design from a start can save you from a lot of redundant work and headaches.

Comment: @DaveNewton why you cannot post it as an answer?

Comment: Oops! I am a bit new to stack overflow. I appreciate the suggestions to clean up the hash but it is for a tutorial

Comment: aserty, [required reading](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for those new to SO (and to Stack Exchange generally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you received some kind of assignment. It's good to practice using horribly structured data, since every once in a while you'll use someone else's code (that you can't change!) that outputs really awkward structures like the one you're dealing with.

You might consider writing a method like the following:

```
def render_desserts(desserts_hash)
  message = "Tonight we have #{desserts_hash.values.flatten.size} delicious desserts: "
  msg_arry = desserts_hash.map do |key, array|
    if array.length > 1
      "#{array.length} #{key}: #{array.map(&:capitalize).join(' and ')}"
    else
      array[0].to_s.split(/[ _]/).map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
    end
  end
  msg_arry[-1] = "and " + msg_arry[-1]
  message += msg_arry.join(', ')
end
```

Which prints out **exactly** what you were asked to print in the original assignment if you run

```
puts render_desserts(menu[:desserts])
```

Comment: But if the data were changed a little, we'd get something like `Tonight we have 4 delicious desserts: Pumpkin Pie, 2 other: Chocolate moose and Twinkies, and Cranberry`, probably not what is desired.  To do it properly lots of changes would be needed, including a way to convert words between singular and plural, as @rewritten mentioned, but I don't think aserty is asking for that.

Comment: You are right it is an assignment and hence the awful data structure. I really appreciate you explaining why it is important to work with bad data structures - the assignment was feeling kind of arbitrary. Anyways, your code is perfect except it doesn't put a period at the end of the sentence, but I fixed this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
a = menu[:desserts].values.flatten
puts "Tonight we have #{a.size} delicious desserts: #{a.map(&:to_s).join(', ').gsub('_',' ')}."
  # => Tonight we have 5 delicious desserts: pumpkin pie, Chocolate Moose, cranberry, mango, cherry.
```

but you should not have a mix of data types in your hash values.  Make them all strings, and all a complete description of the product:

```
def menu
  { diet: @diet, proteins: ["Tofurkey", "Hummus"],
    veggies: [:ginger_carrots , :potatoes , :yams],
    desserts: ({
      :pies  => ["pumpkin pie"],
      :other => ["chocolate Moose"],
      :molds => ["cranberry mold", "mango mold", "cherry mold"]})}
end
```

Then change the `puts` to:

```
puts "Tonight we have #{a.size} delicious desserts:\n  #{a.join(', ')}."
=>  Tonight we have 5 delicious desserts:
=>    pumpkin pie, chocolate moose, cranberry mold, mango mold, cherry mold.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the numebr of desserts:

```
dessert_count = menu[:desserts].values.flatten.size
```

Then (but it's not very clear from your requirements) you want to build a sentence from the different lists:

```
sentences = menu[:desserts].map { |kind, list|
  case list.size
  when 0 then ""
  when 1 then "#{list[0]}".titleize
  else        "#{list.size} #{kind.to_s.pluralize}: #{list.to_sentence.titleize}"
            #  3 molds: Cranberry, Mango and Cherry
  end
end
```

Once you have this, you can build your final sentence:

```
puts "Tonight we have #{dessert_count} delicious desserts: #{sentences.to_sentence}."
```

This is assuming you have `active_support` available, which has the very useful `#to_sentence`, `#titleize` and `#pluralize` methods.